# WPF | Control Menu Checkbox (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a controll menu in WPF. The button in that menu should activate the "Dark mode" that I've already created. Well that's just a simple Click event.
But I'd like to have a CheckBox not a simple Click event.
That's my code in XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Settings">
                <MenuItem Header="_Darkmode" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
```

The C# Code is inconsequential because that's just a sample.

Greetings from the US

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the [`Click`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.click?view=net-5.0) event:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Settings">
        <MenuItem Header="_Darkmode"
                  Click="OnDarkmodeClicked"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You could use the [`Checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.checked?view=net-5.0)/[`Unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.unchecked?view=net-5.0) events after setting the [`IsCheckable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischeckable?view=net-5.0) property:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Settings">
        <MenuItem Header="_Darkmode" 
                  IsCheckable="True"
                  Checked="OnDarkmodeChecked"
                  Unchecked="OnDarkmodeUnchecked"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Or you could bind [`IsChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.menuitem.ischecked?view=net-5.0) to a property in your model:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Settings">
        <MenuItem Header="_Darkmode" 
                  IsCheckable="True"
                  IsChecked="{Binding UseDarkmode}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but you could store a boolean elsewhere, and have a menuitem that looks like this:
XAML code

```
<MenuItem Header="_Blur Background" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Click="BlurOnOff_Click" InputGestureText="Ctrl+B"></MenuItem>
```

Then C# code

```
private void BlurOnOff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        blurOn = blurOn ? false : true;
    }
```

The Blur On/Off is just an example. When the function is called, it updates the boolean to be the opposite of what it was before.